# Refactor PHP method

Tags: php, refactoring, magento2

I'm having Method but it looks so as a noob-monkey code.
is it possible to ask guru to refactor that array and make code shorter as much as it possible. And I want to get into answer by json but it giving me something like

```
"{\"New customer ID\":\"31\"}"
```

is it ok?

```
public function createVoucherStatus($statusCode)
    {
        $voucherStatus = $this->voucherStatusModelFactory->create();
        $voucherStatus->setStatusCode($statusCode);
        try {
            $this->voucherStatusResourceFactory->save($voucherStatus);
            $response = ['New customer ID' => ($voucherStatus->getId())];
            return json_encode($response);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception("Customer is invalid");
        }
    }
```

Thank you so much

Comment: What you're showing is what you would get if you called `json_encode()` again on the returned JSON.

Comment: You are calling `$this->voucherStatusResourceFactory->save($voucherStatus);` two times... ?

Comment: oh,I'm really blind